# How can I replace `eval` in my function?

Tags: python, dictionary, eval, setattr

I know very well that it is not good practice using `eval` in Python. Here is my code:

```
from hashlib import * # added for clarification
def get_hash(self):
        if self.hash_type in ['md5', 'sha1', 'sha224', 'sha256', 'sha384', 'sha512']:
            data = eval(self.hash_type) # <--- how can I replace this?
```

I've heard of the `setattr` function, but I honestly don't know how to implement it.

Is it also possible to do this by using the `map` function?

Note that `'md5', 'sha1', 'sha224'` etc are local variables. When I'm using the `eval` function on one of them, they become functions.

Comment: Why you need eval function?

Comment: What are `md5`, `sha1` etc? Global variables, local variables, functions?

Comment: Do you expect `md5`, `sha1` etc. to be the names of some objects or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getattr`:

```
import hashlib
if self.hash_type in ['md5', 'sha1', 'sha224', 'sha256', 'sha384', 'sha512']:
     func = getattr(hashlib, self.hash_type)
```

Comment: I can't believe how clean this is.

Comment: Apparently it's not working: `TypeError: setattr expected 3 arguments, got 2`.

Comment: @Deneb Why are you using `setattr`?

Comment: I should be crucified for this.. Where was I thinking? Thank you again... I have no words.

Answer (score 3):

Why not store all the information in a dictionary? For example:

```
self.hash_types = {
    'md5': md5,
    'sha1': sha1,
    ...
}
```

Then in `get_hash`:

```
def get_hash(self):
    if self.hash_type in self.hash_types:
        data = self.hash_types[self.hash_type]
```

Alternatively,

```
def get_hash(self):
    data = self.hash_types.get(self.hash_type, self.DEFAULT)
```

Comment: This also seems like a very good example. I was thinking of using a dictionary, but then I though it would make my code a little too messy.

Comment: I prefer this way if you are just trying to get data, but when you are actually accessing function, I feel like Ashwini's answer is more pythonic.